# Why fscanf not working as expected for subsequent calls?

Tags: c, linux, scanf

```
char s[20];
fscanf(stream, "%s", s);
```

I found that it can only work for the first time, subsequent calls will fail.

```
(gdb) p fscanf(stream, "%s", s)
$15 = 1
(gdb) p (char *)s
$17 = 0x7fffffffe770 ""
```

From the above can see that `fscanf` matches `1` character, but not stored to `s`?

**UPDATE**

Is there a way to get corresponding file name of `FILE*`?

file content:

```
a
abc
b
c
e
f
h
hi
```

Comment: I think this question needs more detail, what do you think you are reading from the file? Can you guarantee your buffer is large enough? Do you have more luck with different files?

Comment: @James Greenhalgh ,The buffer is large enough,as the max number of chars per line is only `4`

Answer (score 3):

[fscanf et al](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) return the number of *items* converted, not the number of bytes or characters. So you are successfully converting one *item*, a string in this case, which happens to be empty (`""`).

Comment: `%s` should return non-white-space characters,but it's not the case somehow..`s      Matches  a  sequence of non-white-space characters;`

Comment: You probably need to show part of the contents of the file that you are trying to read around the area where fscanf appears not to be doing what you want.

Comment: Do you mean empty string belong to non-white-space characters?

Comment: I pasted the file content above.

Comment: OK - are there any spaces at the end of the line ? What compiler and OS are you using ? What are the line termination characters (CR, LF, CR+LF) ? How are you opening the file (e.g. `stream = fopen(filename, "r");` ?) ? Does the first line containing "a" read OK ? Is the failure on the second line ("abc") ?